# Stability theory of inverted pendulum

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I started reading the first chapter of Eduardo D. Sontag book *Mathematical Control Theory*.

In the first exercise, the differential equation (obtained from mathematical pendulum linearized at the upper equilibrium point with proportional feedback) is given as

\begin{equation}
\ddot{\varphi}-\sin \varphi+\alpha\varphi=0,
\end{equation}

in which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. The exercise claims that solutions of this equation typically will not approach zero, no matter how the feedback gain $\alpha$ is picked.

By choosing the energy

\begin{equation}
V(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})=\cos \varphi -1 +\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\alpha \varphi^2+\dot{\varphi}^2 \right]
\end{equation}

as a candidate Lyapunov function it is easy to show that $\dot{V}=0$. This implies that $V=\text{const.}$ along solutions.

Now, the author states

> ...that $V(x,0)$ is an analytic function and therefore that its zero
>   at $x=0$ is isolated.

**Why does analyticity imply an isolated zero? For example $V=0$ is also analytic and still does not have isolated zeros.**

---

EDIT: This is my attempt to show that analyticity of $f(x)\not\equiv 0$ (to exclude the trivial case such that all the derivative vanish) in the neighbourhood of $x=0$ for which $f(x=0) =0$ implies that the zero is isolated.

As $f(x)$ is analytic we can expand it as a Taylor expansion

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

evaluated at a point $x_0$ close to the point $x=0$. Now, as we assumed $f(x=0)=0$ we can write

$$0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}x_0^n.$$

If $x=0$ is not an isolated zero, we can find a point $x_0\neq 0$ infinitely close to $x=0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. If that is the case then we can conclude that $x_0=0$ from the Taylor expansion, hence we obtain a contradiction to $x_0\neq 0$.

> Question: Is my way of reasoning correct?

---

**If we assume that $x=0$ is isolated, how can I conclude that there are initial conditions $\varphi(0)=\varepsilon$,$\dot{\varphi}(0)=0$, with arbitrarily small, for which the corresponding solutions do not converge to $\varphi\to 0$ and $\dot{\varphi}\to 0$ for $t\to 0$.**

Comment: He should have written "non-trivial analytic function", as any analytic function with non-isolated zeros is the zero function. This follows directly from the expansion in power series.

Comment: @LutzL: Thank you a lot for your comment. Could you please check, if my edit for showing the isolatedness is correct?

Comment: That is a rather convoluted way of doing it. Just expanding in the root $x_0$ gives $f(x)=(x-x_0)^mg(x)$ where $g$ is analytic as well and $g(x_0)\ne 0$. Then by continuity there is a ball around $x_0$ with $g(x)\ne 0$ and thus $f(x)\ne 0$ for $0<|x-x_0|<r$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will have to think about the last part, it does not seem trivial to me :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point to recognize is that even with that controller input the system is still conservative. This you confirmed with computing that $\dot V=0$. You would need a mechanism that acts as friction $\beta\dot x$, $β>0$, to bleed off energy and sink towards a minimum of the potential function $V(x,0)$ ($=f(α,x)$ in the graph below).

Note that potential around $x=0$ has the expansion
$$
V(x,0)=\frac12(αx^2-(2\sin x/2)^2)=\frac12\left((α-1)x^2+\frac1{12}x^4+\dots\right)
$$
This means that for $α\ge 1$ the potential function has a local minimum at $x=0$ while for $α<1$ this is a local maximum with local minima close by at $x\approx \pm\sqrt{12(1-α)}$ for $α\lessapprox1$.

[image: potential curves for different alpha close to one]

In the phase plane the solutions move along the level curves of $V$. Around a local minimum these are concentric circles, the solutions thus oscillations with the minimum in the middle.

As $V(ε,0)=V(0,\dot x)$ so that $\dot x=\pm\sqrt{αε^2-(2\sin(ε/2))^2}$ the velocity is never zero at $x=0$ for $α\ge 1$, for $ α<1$ the motion never reaches the maximum if starting at rest at a point below that maximum. There are non-zero solutions of $\sqrtα ε=2\sin(ε/2)$ so that a solution converging to $x=0$ exists, however that is unstable, any small deviation leads to oscillating behavior, which is not what a controller should do.

Comment: +1 For your answer. I will have to read it carefully first before accepting it.

Comment: In your last part you say that $V(\varepsilon,0)=V(0,\dot{x})$. I don't understand what you mean by that because at the first glance this does not make sense, as the first expression contains $\varepsilon$ and the second does not contain $\varepsilon$ and is also different from the structure.

Comment: If $x(0)=ε$, $\dot x(0)=0$ so that $V(ε,0)>0$ then there are points on the level curve of $V(x,y)=V(ε,0)$ where $x=0$. The value of $y$ at these points then is a solution to $V(ε,0)=V(0,y)$. Now check that the solutions never go back on a level curve and there will be a $t$ where $x(t)=0$, $\dot x(t)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

> This is my attempt to solve it. Is not intended as an answer (please feel free to comment if there
>   is something not correct).

As we know that $V=\text{const.}$ we can write:

\begin{equation}
V(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})=\cos \varphi -1 +\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\alpha \varphi^2+\dot{\varphi}^2 \right]=\dfrac{c}{2}.
\end{equation}

Using the initial conditions $\varphi(0)=\varepsilon$ and $\dot{\varphi}(0)=0$ we can obtain

$$c = 2\left[\cos(\varepsilon)-1\right]+\alpha\varepsilon^2.$$

Hence, we can solve for $\dot{\varphi}$ to obtain

$$\dot{\varphi}(t)=\pm\sqrt{2\left[\cos \varepsilon-\cos\varphi \right]+\alpha\left[\varepsilon^2-\varphi^2 \right]}.$$

By the last expression, we see that there are trajectories that have a strictly positive derivative. Hence the trajectories do not converge to $0$.